Create new SQL records in instances of duplicates
I have a SQL parent table "Notices" that has two foreign key columns, NoteId and LocationId, to a secondary table, "Notes." These two columns share the same table and will at times share the same ID on the same record or across multiple records. I've addressed the C# API code that causes this dupe reference to occur, but I need to clean the DB.
Example of Notices table:

Example of Notes table:

Originally, I was addressing this as a "keep the latest, delete the dupes, and move on" scenario, but after seeing the result on Dev data, I want to try to retain/salvage the existing Prod records and references and create new instances of the "duplicates." End goal, I want to create new Note records to have a (1 Notice to 2 Note) unique record relationship for all records.
Goal for Notices table:

Goal for Notes table:

Additional scenario that I would like to take into account:
There are instances where NoteIds are shared across Notice records. See example below.

I want to ultimately make each NoteId and LocationId on each Notice record unique across the board by creating new Note records to avoid any accidental cross/duplicate-references. Goal of that scenario below.


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
